# Implementing Edge Scroll/Swipe on Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, scroll, swipe, motionevent

I am trying to implement a scrolling/swiping mechanism similar to what we see on Google Maps. I.e. relatively central motion on the screen affects the map whilst swiping from the left starting from outside the screen opens the side menu.

I have my main activity which extends FragmentActivity and has a simple side menu (**menu**) which is currently accessed via a button (**btnSlide**). I want to be able to open the side menu via an edge scroll (like google maps) but any swipes or motion affects which fragment is shown and changes the fragment.

I have tried using [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and implementing [GestureDetector.OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) but I can't get any listeners to pick up the motion. All motion effects the Fragment.

Code sample below. **CustomHorizontalScreenView** is what lets me have a simple side menu its just a custom **HorizontalScrollView**.

Any help would be appreciated !

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{
    private CustomHorizontalScreenView scrollView;
    private View app;
    private View menu;
    private Button btnSlide;
    private boolean POST_LOGS = false;
    private CameraCollectionPageAdapter mCameraCollectionPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        scrollView = (CustomHorizontalScreenView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_horizontal_screen_view, null);
        setContentView(scrollView);

        menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.side_menu, null);
        app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this.getApplicationContext(), this);

        btnSlide = (Button) app.findViewById(R.id.buttonSettings);
        btnSlide.setOnClickListener(new ClickListenerForScrolling(scrollView, menu));

        final View[] children = new View[] { menu, app };

        // Scroll to app (view[1]) when layout finished.
        int scrollToViewIdx = 1;
        scrollView.initViews(children, scrollToViewIdx, new SizeCallbackForMenu(btnSlide));

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        startUp(prefs);
    }

    private void startUp(SharedPreferences prefs){
        //Setting Dimensions
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(MeanwhileConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH, display.getWidth());
        editor.putInt(MeanwhileConstants.SCREEN_HEIGHT, display.getHeight());
        editor.commit();
    }

    /********** Control ****************/
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        setupUI(prefs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    }

    /*********** UI Stuff ***********/
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void setupUI(SharedPreferences prefs){
        String currentCamera = prefs.getString(MeanwhileConstants.CURRENT_CAMERA_ID, null);
        LinkedList<Camera> cameras = getPrioritizedCameras(prefs, currentCamera);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        mCameraCollectionPageAdapter = new CameraCollectionPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mViewPager, this.getApplicationContext(), cameras);
        mCameraCollectionPageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCameraCollectionPageAdapter);

    }
}
```